# How do I add a / in an url_for statement?

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to say: go to additemtocart/`1`

`<a href="{{url_for('additemtocart/1')}}">add to cart</a>`

But all I get is an error message saying:

> werkzeug.routing.BuildError:

Could not build url for endpoint '`additemtocart/1`'. Did you mean 'additemtocart' instead?

python code:

````
carts = []

def addtocart(item):
    carts.append({'name': checkusername(), 'items': item})
    print(carts)

@app.route('/additemtocart/<id>')
def additemtocart(id):
    if checklogin() == True:
        try:
            title = db.get_select_product(int(id))[5]
            addtocart(title)
            print(title + ' has been added to your shopping cart')
            return redirect(url_for('cart'))
        except:
            return 'item does not exist'
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))```
````

Comment: better to share schema

Comment: what do you mean by 'schema'?

Comment: yes your view, how you implement the `additemtocart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

`<a href="{{url_for('additemtocart/1')}}">add to cart</a>`

to

`<a href="{{url_for('additemtocart', ID=1)}}">add to cart</a>`

this way you are passing variable/non static component with the function/end point